# Making an unsigned sis - error: No rule to make target `unsigned_sis'. Stop

Tags: qt, symbian, sis, symbian3

I'm trying to make an unsigned sis package of my application, however I get the aforementioned error from QtCreator.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem with Qt 4.6.3. Qt 4.7.3 creates unsigned .sis files without any issues, but 4.6.x doesn't. If the version of Qt isn't important for you, upgrade to 4.7.
I'm looking for another way to solve this, because I want to support old devices that don't work with Qt 4.7

**UPD:**
I found two ways to create unsigned sis:

1. Create a signed sis file with QtCreator and remove signature with [Syscontents](http://symbiandev.cdtools.net/) tool
2. Copy template .pkg, edit it a bit and create sis with makesis commandline tool.

I used the second way, because I use localized installation file. Localized installations work bad in Qt 4.6.3 out of box, so I had to create custom .pkg file

Comment: I ended up using the Syscontents tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install unsigned application to the phone. Try to sign it and see if it works better

Comment: I can't even create the sis package. I edited my question to be more clear. My apologies.

Comment: Can you make some Qt sample projects to work? Then you could check out the project settings from them